# Updating DB Tables Using PHP Dont Work

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, pdo, get

i've made a website, and i made a control panel for it for admin
now iwant to make admin able to add more users to be admins from the control panel
its worked 
but i want to make him able to edit them also ( like the usernames and passwords )
i wrote the code but it didnt work and i think the problem maybe with the `$editget = $_GET['euid'];` it dosent give the number in the url that should be www.example.com/admin/index.php?adpa=users&euid=4 , so it should get me the number 4 
i did the same thing with delectation it works and the GET gave me the number after deluid=
so where im going wrong

here is the code :

```
$eusername = $_POST['eusername'];
$epassword = $_POST['epassword'];
#===========================================================#
if (isset($_POST['edit']) and $_POST['edit'] == 'user') {
    $editget = $_GET['euid'];
    $edituserinfo = $db->query("update user set username='$eusername', password='$epassword' where user_id='$editget'");

    if (isset($edituserinfo)) {
    die ("
    <center>
    <div class='head'>تــــــــم</div>
    <div class='bodypanel'>
    <br>
    تــــعديل بيـــانات الـــمدير بنـــجاح
    <br>
    <br>
    </div>
    </center>
    <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='4; url=?cpages=users' />
    ");
}
}
```

and here is the edit form code :

```
if ($_REQUEST['euid']) {

    $edituid = $db->query("select * from user where user_id='$editu'");
    $redit = $edituid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    echo "
    <form action='?cpages=users' method='post'>
        <table width='100%' align='center' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='0'>
            <tr>
                <td class='tbl' colspan='2'>تعديل بيانات مدير</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class='tblrl' align='left'>اسم المدير : </td>
                <td class='tblrl' align='right'><input type='text' name='eusername' value='".$redit->username."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class='tblrl' align='left'>كلمة سر المدير : </td>
                <td class='tblrl' align='right'><input type='text' name='epassword' value='".$redit->password."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class='tblb' colspan='2' align='center'><input class='buttons' type='submit' value='تعديل'/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type='hidden' name='edit' value='user' />
    </form>";

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the userId in the form

change

```
<form action='?cpages=users' method='post'>
```

to

```
<form action='?cpages=users&euid=" . $_GET['euid'] . "' method='post'>
```

Answer (score -1):

your problem is here in the form in this line

`<form action='?cpages=users' method='post'>`

your taking it to users page but there is no euid in there so just add
`&euid=" . $_GET['euid'] . "` to get it to work fine